# Android studio problems with android.R resources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

When I needed Android's resources from android.R, Android Studio didn't recognize keyword android, so I imported by myself with the line of code below:

```
import android.R;
```

after this, all appearances of R. were from android.R, i.e. it didn't recognize my own resources

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try removing the import android.R;  and cleaning the project?

Comment: You should not import android.R.

Answer (score 2):

remove android.R import and try import your package resource like this.

```
import com.yourpackage.name.R;
```